# Why am I getting the error "type=bpy_struct__new__(type): expected a single argument" when creating a PointerProperty for PropertyGroup?

Tags: python, scripting

I created classes for a PropertyGroup and then attempted to register it in a register function.

```
class MyCustomPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
        #Property definitions here

def register():
        bpy.types.Scene.MyCustomProperty = bpy.types.PointerProperty(type = MyCustomPropertyGroup)
```

I’d followed multiple examples that suggested using PointerProperty to attach a PropertyGroup to be used in other classes, but I got the error `type=bpy_struct__new__(type): expected a single argument` and couldn't figure out how to get past this issue. Is this a valid function to use? I’ve tried with Blender 3.4.1 and even updated to 3.6.2 in hopes it was a bug to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the function works properly if you’re actually using it. [bpy.types.PointerProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointerProperty.html) is a class. [bpy.props.PointerProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.PointerProperty) is the function to use.

Comment: Hehe I can relate, I've once lost quite a bit of time following a rabbit hole trying to solve the exact same bug to only then finally realize that was the problem. The error message could be improved I guess :)